# Translucent JFrame leaves rendering artifacts when frame repacked

Tags: java, macos, swing

When I change a JLabel's font size or contents in a translucent JFrame, then call pack() on the frame, a ghosted version of the previous contents is visible. This only happens on macOS. The same code works fine on Windows.

Here's an enlarged example of what happens: 
[image]

Here is code to reproduce the problem; make sure the JFrame is on top of a white background to better see the problem, then click the "Bigger" and "Smaller" buttons:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Transparent Frame");
            frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", true);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 25));

            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            contentPane.setOpaque(false);
            contentPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 25));

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello cruel world");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            contentPane.add(label);

            contentPane.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Bigger") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(label.getFont().getSize() + 1f));
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }));
            contentPane.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Smaller") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(label.getFont().getSize() - 1f));
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }));

            frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried changing all components to non-opaque. I've tried revalidating the content pane after packing. What do I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Swing doesn't know how to paint transparent backgrounds properly so you need to do the painting yourself.

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a couple of solutions.

But to set a frame transparent you should be using the `setOpacity(...)` method of the frame. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create Translucent Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html);

Comment: Java has supported transparent backgrounds since Java 7, I think.  My understanding is that setOpacity is for uniform transparent for each pixel, and setBackground with a color with alpha level activates per-pixel translucency.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod, No Java doesn't support transparent backgrounds on Swing components. Components like JPanel, JCheckBox are different than a top level component like a JFrame. You are trying to set transparency on a JPanel.